# Free string returned by X509_NAME_oneline

Tags: c, string, openssl, free

I am trying to use a simple SSL example.

This is some code:

```
void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{
    X509 *cert;
    char *line;

    cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
    if ( cert != NULL )
    {
        printf("Server certificates:\n");
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
        printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
        free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
        X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
    }
    else
        printf("No certificates.\n");
}
```

Program crashes in the `free(line)` lines of code. Without these lines, the  program works without crashes. If I remove these lines I am afraid in this case that some allocated resources will not be freed - what should I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the point in printing 0 bytes of data? That's what you're doing.

Comment: Are you sure the allocation is happening in the first place? please check the error codes of the functions SSL_get_peer_certificates and X509_etc to see what they return in cases of failure

Answer (score 7):

Not sure, Maybe you can use:

OPENSSL_free(line);

I just use this code on my windows client, and it works fine :)

Answer (score 2):

According to the description of the function X509_NAME_oneline in http://linux.die.net/man/3/x509_name_oneline, if the pointer `line` is `NULL`, then the function will dynamically allocate memory for it. Otherwise, it just return the pointer `line`.

I would like to pre-allocate the space and release manually. As the following:

```
#define MAX_SIZE 1000
char* line = new char[ MAX_SIZE + 1 ];
printf( "%s\n", X509_NAME_oneline( X509_get_subject_name( cert ), line, MAX_SIZE ) );
delete[] line;   // thanks moowar's advice
```

Comment: scalar-delete on a pointer from array-new is incorrect (but will probably technically work fine in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to try something like this:

```
#define MAX_DN_SIZE 2000 // whatever big enough size here

char line[MAX_DN_SIZE+1];
....
X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), line, MAX_DN_SIZE ); // convert
line[MAX_DN_SIZE] = '\0'; // set paranoid terminator in case DN is exactly MAX_DN_SIZE long
```

and remove the 'free'. Of course this will print just the first MAX_DN_SIZE chars of your DN :)